# Synchronous reading of multiple TCP responses

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I'm writing a simple POP3 client. When I make for example `LIST` request to a POP3 server it responds with indexes and sizes (bytes) of available messages. It looks like this:

```
+OK 3 messages\r\n
1 103\r\n
2 140\r\n
3 184\r\n
```

I'm using `boost::asio::read_until` with `\r\n` as a delimiter, but this way I can't keep synchronization, because sometimes only the first part is being read, e.g.  `+OK 3 messages\r\n1 103\r\n` and that's the optimistic case. I want my program to wait for the last part of a message. The only solution I came up with is to put `sleep()` after making a request and before reading it, but it doesn't seem to be reliable nor convenient solution.
What are better ways for dealing with that?

Comment: If you want to have **synchronous** reading then why do you use a library for **asynchronous** processing of data in the first place? Either your code is supposed to be event based or not.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that's a good question, but I'm too far with my work and too short on time.

Comment: The proper way to handle this in an asynchronous way would be to simply collect and combine the parts of the response over multiple read events and process it once you have received the full response. The wrong way would be to somehow wait with a busy loop or with a sleep since in this case your program could not handle other events.

Comment: @user207421 Thank You, and sorry for stupid question, this's my first contact with network programming

Comment: @user207421 clearly you have not actually read the [POP3 spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1939#page-6), because that is not how the `LIST` response actually works, not even close. The text following the `+OK` is *arbitrary* and should not be parsed or relied on for processing. The response is *actually* terminated by a `.\r\n` line after the final message is listed. THAT is the delimiter you need to wait for

Comment: @RemyLebeau Curiously enough I have read it, but it would be 20-25 years ago. Alas, memory is fallible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [POP3 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) the secret is to wait for a proper delimiter, which is `.\r\n`

credits: @RemyLebeau

Comment: The terminator is the same line in both cases: `.\r\n`. Read the spec again more carefully, especially [section 3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1939#section-3) which describes the format of ALL multi-line responses.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ohh, You're right. It seems, that`\r\n.\r\n` worked by some coincidence.